# Apache Ozone. No REST API in the newer versions. How to communicate from third applications?

Tags: hadoop, ozone

I can find REST API docs for the alpha versions of apache Ozone. However, I can find it for the current version (0.5.0) Has it been removed?

Is there a way to communicate from any application with OZone without using the specific Java Client or shell commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's S3 compatible. You'd therefore be able to use any S3 client

Comment: Thanks, I realized that there are S3 client implementations for .NET, for example.

Comment: Hi again. Did you tried it any time? I am experiencing a weird behaviour. When I call PutObjectAsync method on the client, instead of having a key being created, a new bucket is created on the root of the volume that ozones uses for S3. From AWS cli the key is properly created with the put-object subcommand

Comment: I described the issue deeper here, if you could help. Thanks anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966945/apache-ozone-aws-s3-net-api-putobject-is-creating-a-bucket-instead-of-a-key